# Stunned silence/disbelief

Tags: adjectives

What meaning of "stunned" applies to the following sentences where **stunned** modifies abstract nouns forming an adverbial?

what is the linguistic term for such a behavior?
What other adjectives act in a similar way?

*I sat in stunned silence*, 
 *I reacted to the news with stunned disbelief*

Answer (score 1):

Stunned is an adjective meaning:

> very shocked or surprised:
>
> - They stood in stunned silence beside the bodies.

Probably the term you are looking for is “modifier”:

> A modifier is a word or group of words that modifies another word or group. In some descriptions of grammar, only words that are used before a noun are called modifiers.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

The linguistic term for how "stunned" is used in your sentence is secondary predicate.

Comment: but it's the person who is stunned, not the silence/disbelief

Comment: Please could you add some references to back up your claim?

Comment: @GJC My reading is that the silence is a result of the stunned, making it a circumstantial secondary predicate. Please feel free to disagree. This is a complex topic, and I always welcome the opportunity to learn.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Two references: Irimia, M. 2005. Types of secondary predication. University of Toronto (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.465.8195&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and Saurenbach, Holger 2005 Challenging discrete approaches to secondary-predicate constructions. Universität Regensburg. (https://epub.uni-regensburg.de/10310/1/DissertationHolgerSaurenbach.pdf)